# checking if element is in list in gae template

Tags: python, google-app-engine, templates

I have class:

```
class Article(db.Model):
     visitedBy = db.ListProperty(int)

context = {
    "article": Article(),
    "id": 3
}
```

In template I try do it:

```
{% if id in article.visitedBy %}
     <p>Eureka</p>
{% endif %}
```

But I got error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError: 'if' statement improperly formatted
```

My question is how can I check in template if some item is in list?

Comment: which `django` version are you using?

Comment: where can I check it? template I have from `from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template`

Comment: Are you using `runtime: python` or `runtime: python27` in your `app.yaml` ?

Comment: `if id in article` looks weird, did you mean `if id in article.visitedBy` ?

Comment: The default django version for the python 2.5 runtime is 0.96, which doesn't support this syntax. There are several SO questions that will tell you how to switch to a newer version.

Comment: you can add one link if it is so good known problem. It would be better help then sentense that in the Internet is many place, where you can find solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was older version of django. Using this tutorial

http://code.google.com/intl/pl/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/

I change version to newer and now it works very well.

Olny problem was that I haven't got jinja2 library. It could be installed using this link:

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/intro/